# Perfmon metrics collector throw error

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, perfmon

I have the follwing Jmeter script, everything is ok except that the perfmon metric collector are throwing errors and I dont know what I am missing:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that [Perfmon Metrics Collector listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) is not able to establish connection with the PerfMon Server Agent

Make sure you:

1. Download [PerfMon Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) onto the machine running JMeter and on your `192.168.56.160` host
2. Run PerfMon Server Agents on both machines
3. Make sure that port `4444` is not blocked by firewall

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for detailed installation and configuration instructions